# How to change camera default settings programatically

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working with an android camera and I'd like to capture an image from the front camera even though the camera's default setting would be the back camera.

Is this possible?  When i try to capture an image from my app, the back camera will open since my default settings is the back camera.

Comment: Post the code where you add camera

Comment: `if (!getPackageManager()
         .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)`
           .show();
     } else {
      this.camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
     }

Answer (score 0):

Camera.open(cameraNo); cameraNO 1 for front,0 for back camera.

Answer (score 0):

Find the front camera id using ,

```
private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
     int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
      CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
      Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
        cameraId = i;
        break;
    }
  }
return cameraId;
```

}

and open camera using this id.

```
 camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
```

find the example [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html)

Comment: it can check only which camera u use? not that default settings changed.

Comment: camera = Camera.open(cameraId); will open camera with id cameraId.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

try this code if you just want to start front camera from default camera app.

Comment: Hey i tried this code , it is working in Samsung devices , but it is not working in other devices